# If T is a stopping time and if $X_n$ is martingale then so is $X_{T \wedge n}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability

Suppose that $(X_n,F_n)$ be a martingale and uniformly integrable.  Show that if $T$ is a stopping time then $(X_{n \wedge T},F_{n \wedge T})$ is also a uniformly integrable martingale.  The uniformly integrable part is trivial.

My attempt:

First note that $X_{min\{n+1,T\}}=X_{n+1}-(X_{n+1}-X_{T})I_{\{n<T\}}$.  Since $n \wedge T \leq n$, we have $E(X_{n+1 \wedge T} | F_n)=E(X_{n+1}|F_n)-E(X_{n+1}|F_n)I_{n<T}+E(X_{T} | F_n)I_{n<T}$.  Now if $n<T$ then $X_{n \wedge T}=X_n$ and $E(X_{n+1 \wedge T} | F_n)=X_n=X_{n \wedge T}$.  Now if $T \leq n$ then then the two terms on the last two terms on the LHS are zero and we get $E(X_{n+1 \wedge T} | F_n)=X_n \neq X_{n \wedge T}$.  I'm not sure where the problem is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your inequality in the indicator function is in the wrong direction, it should be $$X_{min\{n+1,T\}}=X_{n+1}-(X_{n+1}-X_{T})I_\color{red}{{\{n>T\}}}$$
Second, I don't think that distinguishing between the random events $n>T$ and $n\le T$ is a proper way to proceed, you should just stick with the indicator functions all the way.

As for your problem, first notice that
$$ X_{n+1 \wedge T} = X_{n \wedge T} + (X_{n+1} - X_n)\mathbf 1_{T\ge n+1}$$
(i.e., the process $(X_{\boldsymbol\cdot \wedge T})$ can only be incremented at time $n+1$ if $T$ has not yet been reached).
You then have
$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[X_{n+1 \wedge T} \mid F_n] &= \mathbb E[X_{n \wedge T} + (X_{n+1} - X_n)\mathbf 1_{T\ge n+1}\mid F_n] \\
&= \mathbb E[X_{n \wedge T}\mid F_n] + \mathbf 1_{T\ge n+1}\mathbb E[(X_{n+1} - X_n)\mid F_n]\end{align} $$
Finally notice that $X_{n\wedge T}$ is $F_n$-measurable and use martingale property of $X$ to conclude.